# Match the first occurrence of child node

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an xml document

```
 <body>
      <heading>Main Heading</heading>
      <para>
       <text>para 1</text>
      </para>
      <para>
        <heading>heading 2</heading>
        <text> para 2</text>
      </para>
      <para>
         <heading>heading 3</heading>
         <text>para 3</text>
       </para>
    </body>
```

I want to match the first occurrence of heading element and add some text to it. I just want the first occurrence of heading and heading should be a child node of para element.

so the output should be like below

```
 <body>
      <heading>Main Heading</heading>
      <para>
       <text>para 1</text>
      </para>
     <para>
        <heading>**This is a first heading found** heading 2</heading>
        <text> para 2</text>
      </para>
     <para>
    <heading>heading 3</heading>
        <text>para 3</text>
      </para>
    </body>
```

Comment: Technically the first occurrence of `<heading>` element is the one for Main Heading. So your requirement is the first heading element which is a child of `<para>`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
para[heading][1]/heading[1]
```

It would match the first heading element inside the first para-that-contains-any-headings.

Example XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="para[heading][1]/heading[1]">
    <xsl:copy>**First heading** <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output on your example:

```
<body>
      <heading>Main Heading</heading>
      <para>
       <text>para 1</text>
      </para>
      <para>
        <heading>**First heading** heading 2</heading>
        <text> para 2</text>
      </para>
      <para>
         <heading>heading 3</heading>
         <text>para 3</text>
       </para>
    </body>
```

If there might be `<para>` elements elsewhere in the XML than just nested directly under the `<body>` then you would be safer with a more specific match expression, namely

```
/body/para[heading][1]/heading[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with the `position()` of `para` since your first `<heading>` is a child of `<para>`. And para occurs once before it has a child called `<heading>` so you need the second `<para>`.

Apply this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//para[position()=2]/heading">
    <xsl:element name="heading">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('**This is a first heading found**',' ',.)"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to your source XML and you will get this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
<heading>Main Heading</heading>
<para>
    <text>para 1</text>
</para>
<para>
    <heading>**This is a first heading found** heading 2</heading>
    <text> para 2</text>
</para>
<para>
    <heading>heading 3</heading>
    <text>para 3</text>
</para>
</body>
```

PS: I just noticed you want XSLT 2.0 - my solution is XSLT 1.0. I am not sure if there is a difference.

Comment: Thanks peter, but cant we have a more generic solution instead of saying position =2 because it might happen that the input will have heading in para 3 instead of 2 so although this work but I am looking for more generic solution.